# Fixing my search form in HTML with embedded PHP?

Tags: php, html

So I have a PHP page which has an ordered list that I am scanning from a text file which looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code for it as well:

```
 <?php
       foreach (file("Files/music.txt") as $music){
           list($title,$artist,$link) = explode(",",$music);
          ?>

               <li>
                    <a href=<?php echo $link ?>><?php echo $title ?> by <?php echo $artist ?></a>
               </li>

      <?php } ?>
      </ol>
      </div>
```

What I need is to be able to search the title for the song and to only display that with the form I have in the picture. I have to use only the $_GET and a function to make it work. Here is the code for the form that I am messing around with:

```
 <form action="blog.php">
          Search for Title:
          <input type="text" name="title">
          <input type="submit" value="Search">
          <br>
          <a href="blog.php?sort=True">Sort by song title</a>
          <a href="blog.php?sort=False"> Unsorted</a>    
         <?php
         function printSongs($searchTitles=""){
            if(isset($searchTitles)){
                global $title;
                if ($searchTitle ==  $title){
                    echo $title;
                }
            }
         }
         $userInput = $_GET["title"];
            printSongs($userInput);


         ?>

      </form>
```

Any advice would help alot. Thank you!

Comment: Whenever I search the for the song it just refreshes the page and remains the same.

Comment: Are you trying to use links to submit a form? What is the purpose of the links? How do you execute your search?

Comment: No, the links are just to send the user to a youtube link of the song. I am trying for the user to search for the song's name and it prints out only that song. So if a user types in "Humble" it would show up as: "Humble by Kendrick Lamar" and the other two would not be displayed. Sorry if I am not explaining this well.

Answer (score -1):

try using The SplFileObject class in PHP try this code

```
<?php
      function printSongs($searchTitles=""){
       $file = new SplFileObject("Files/music.txt");
        $music="";
        while (!$file->eof()) {
            $music= $file->fgets();

            $data= explode(",",$music);
            if (in_array($searchTitles, $data))
            {
              //match is found 
              echo data[1];
            }
        }
        }
        $userInput = $_GET["title"];
        printSongs($userInput);
        ?>
```